# How to SELECT fields from 2 table order by datetime-field from both table?

Tags: php, datetime, sql-order-by, field, multiple-tables

my table info:
table 'entry1' have fields 'id' 'title' 'username' 'date_post' and other fields
table 'entry2' have fields 'id' 'title' 'username' 'date_post' ant other fields

with more info: 
1) 'id' in table 'entry1' is not the same as 'id' in table 'entry2'
2) field 'date_post' from both table are type of datetime

what i want: I want to select 'id' 'title' 'username' and 'date_post' from both table
and order by 'date_post' DESC from both table in a statement.

Sorry all, I'm very new to PHP and my english is not good. It's very difficult to ask.

Comment: PHP & MySql? We have to know what language and data store you are using to provide any help at all.

Answer (score 1):

My working code is:

```
$sql="(SELECT title, date_post FROM entry1 WHERE user_id=$user_id) UNION 
      (SELECT title, date_post FROM entry2 WHERE user_id=$user_id) UNION
      (SELECT title, date_post FROM entry3  WHERE user_id=$user_id)
      ORDER  BY date_post DESC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that both table have same identical column names and types. Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM entry1
UNION
SELECT * FROM entry2
ORDER BY date_post DESC
```

Comment: more info: I use PHP and 'id' is int, 'title' and 'username' are varchar , 'date_post' is datetime. Every row has its own 'id' and 'date_post' which different in both 2 tables, but i'd try to select 'username' and 'title' from both tables orderd by 'date_post' from both tables.

Comment: thanks Jonas. I'd try SELECT * FROM entry1
UNION
SELECT * FROM entry2
ORDER BY date_post DESC